# URL, which automatically close tab

Tags: urls

I need some url, which close tab on Mozilla Firefox.

So, 
I paste the url in the searching box. After it loads, the panel will closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript can only close tabs/windows that have been created by JavaScript on the same page for security reasons.

You could add a userscript that runs outside of page context and reacts to certain tags within the page, with Grease Monkey for example. But that would require the user to have that plugin + your script installed, it won't "just work" if the open the page.